# How to change gamestates in LibGdx using stacks

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a game in android like flappy bird and I am able to go from the menu state to the playState but when the game is over and when I try to get the menu state back it just gives me the background or sometimes a white screen.

```
public class FlappyDemo extends ApplicationAdapter {//ApplicatoonListener

public static final int width=480;
public static final int height=800;
public static final String title="Flappy Bird";
public GameStateManager gsm;
/*private*/public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
public void create () {
    spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
    gsm=new GameStateManager();
    gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);



}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    gsm.render(spriteBatch);


}
```

}

```
public abstract class State {
OrthographicCamera cam;
Vector3 mouse;
GameStateManager gsm;
public State(GameStateManager gsm){
    this.gsm=gsm;
    mouse=new Vector3();

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
}
public abstract void handleInput();
public abstract void update(float dt);
public abstract void render(SpriteBatch sb);
public abstract void dispose();
```

}

```
public class GameStateManager {

private Stack<State> states;

public GameStateManager(){
    states=new Stack<State>();
}
public void push(State state){
    states.push(state);

    }
public void pop(){
    states.pop();
}

public void set(State state){
    states.pop().dispose();
    states.push(state);


}


public void update(float dt){
    states.peek().update(dt);

}
public void render(SpriteBatch sb){
    states.peek().render(sb);
}
```

}

```
public class MenuState extends State {

Texture background;
Texture playBtn;
public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    background=new Texture("bg.png");
    playBtn=new Texture("buttonflappy.jpg");
}

@Override
public void handleInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        gsm.push(new PlayState(gsm));
    }

}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(background,0,0, 1100,1800);
    sb.draw(playBtn,1100/2, 1800/2);
    sb.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    playBtn.dispose();
    background.dispose();

}
```

}

so first I call the push method and pass it the MENUSTATE and than in the menustate I call the push method and pass it the PlayState to start the game and in the PLayState I have got the gameplay, cameras,viewports. Now when I say that if the bird hits the tube or the ground the menustate should be called again all I get is a green screen which is the background of the playstate.

```
  if (tube.collide(bird.getBirdBound())) {

                gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));

            }
            if (bird.getPosition().y <= ground.getHeight() + offset) {

                gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));

            }
```

this is the calling method to the gamestate manager when the game ends and the menustate should be called.
So can anyone tell me how can I get the menustate back instead of getting the background color i.e green.
Really appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: the question is that I am getting the background color i.e "green" when I am wanting to change the game state from the Play State to the MenuState so why am I getting the background only instead of getting the menustate. I can't figure this out.

Comment: The relevant code is missing. For instance what is a "State" class and what is the implementation of "render" of for its subclasses (like MenuState) or what calls the gamestatemanager to run the render & update functiosn. And why would you implement a stack this way and not just use the Game and screen classes libGDX provides?

Comment: updated the states class please check it out and I actually am new to all this so followed a tutorial on how to make this game and so in the tutorial the person was using stacks and so did I and than I started making changes to the game accordingly but I am stuck on this thing.

Comment: Why are you using a stack if you destroy the current state and create a new instance of a state? This way you will only ever have a single state on the stack and really have no use for it. The reason you should use a Stack is so you can "stack" states.

Comment: Even if I do not create a new instance but just recall the previous state I still have the same problem. i.e if I push the menustate first and than push the playstate and than use the pop method to recall the menustate it still gives the same problem.

Comment: AFAIK you need to clearColor on every render call. However quite frankly I think you should not continue down this path. Look into "screen" and "game" classes. Check out this tutorial: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game

Comment: I'll look into it as well.

Comment: A stack doesn't make sense for game states. It would be used for something like a deep menu tree. With game states, you likely want to jump from one state to any other state, and probably want to keep the pause and game screens in memory simultaneously for fast swapping.

Comment: I have already used this method and it would make things very difficult to again go back and do it with Screens and so would really appreciate if someone could help me using stacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it the problem was that I was not changing the camera position. SO what I did was that in the menustate I used the camera and set its position cam.setToOrtho(false,1100,1800) the position where I had drawn the background and updated the camera so now when in the playstate I poped the current state and went back to to the menustate my camera was pointing at the menustate insted of the green color.

Answer (score 0):

You do not clear the previously rendered color to the framebuffer. I see you only call glClearColor on create. Try this render method:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    gsm.render(spriteBatch);
}
```

Comment: I changed the method in the FlappyDemo class but still the same result. Could it be that the camera is still pointing onto the PlayState when I am calling the menustate?

Comment: Depends on your PlayState implementation i guess. You don't seem to even use the camera in menu state

Comment: also, if you do have to use the stack, use it correctly. In stead of pushing another menu screen on the stack, you should pop the top game screen to go back to the main menu